# Oracle returns wrong values with LENGTH and INSTR

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm aiming to retrieve the position of chars in a string, plus the length of a string.

The value of the `notes` field in the  `internal_notes` table, for the row with `ticket_id` equal to 1679467247 is literally 'this is a test note'.

When I use the functions against the literal stirngs they work, but when I retrieve the info directly from the table column, the values are just wrong.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

```sql
select notes,
       LENGTH(notes),
       INSTR(notes,' ')
FROM   internal_notes
where  ticket_id = 1679467247

union

select 'this is a test note',
       LENGTH('this is a test note'),
       INSTR('this is a test note',' ')
from   dual
```

This returns the following:

```
NOTES               LENGTH(NOTES) INSTR(NOTES,' ')
------------------- ------------- ----------------
this is a test note            32                11
this is a test note            19                5
```

Comment: What does `SELECT notes, DUMP(notes) FROM internal_notes where ticket_id = 1679467247;` output?

Comment: What is the datatype of the `notes` column?

Comment: You're assuming that the values in column internal_notes.notes are identical to the literal string 'this is a test note'. That probably is not the case, there could be control characters, trailing and leading spaces, etc. Check with DUMP what the column contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this apparent inconsistency if you have zero-width characters in the value; for example:

```
create table internal_notes(ticket_id number, notes varchar2(32 char));
insert into internal_notes(ticket_id, notes)
values (1679467247, unistr('\200c\200cthis is a test note\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c\200c'));
insert into internal_notes(ticket_id, notes)
values (1679467248, unistr('\200c\200cthis is a test note'));
insert into internal_notes(ticket_id, notes)
values (1679467249, 'this is a test note');

select notes,
       LENGTH(notes),
       INSTR(notes,' ')
FROM   internal_notes
where  ticket_id = 1679467247;

NOTES                            LENGTH(NOTES) INSTR(NOTES,'')
-------------------------------- ------------- ---------------
‌‌this is a test note‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌                         32               7
```

I said 'apparent inconsistency' because those numbers are correct; they just don't look it if you can't see some of the characters. Invisible characters still count.

As @MTO suggested you can use [the `dump()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DUMP.html#GUID-A05793C9-B35D-4BA7-B68C-E3693BCF47A5) to see exactly what is stored in the table, in decimal or hex representation, or mixed with 'normal' characters which can be a bit easier to interpret:

```
select notes,
       LENGTH(notes),
       INSTR(notes,' '),
       dump(notes, 1000) as dmp
FROM   internal_notes;

NOTES                            LENGTH(NOTES) INSTR(NOTES,'')
-------------------------------- ------------- ---------------
DMP                                                                                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
‌‌this is a test note‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌                         32               7 
Typ=1 Len=58: e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,a, ,t,e,s,t, ,n,o,t,e,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,e2,80,
8c                                                                                                                                                                    

‌‌this is a test note                         21               7 
Typ=1 Len=25: e2,80,8c,e2,80,8c,t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,a, ,t,e,s,t, ,n,o,t,e                                                                                                 

this is a test note                         19               5 
Typ=1 Len=19: t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,a, ,t,e,s,t, ,n,o,t,e
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=489227603a3025ca8e88a0174d122246) - though that is showing the zero-width characters as question marks, unlike SQL Developer and SQL*Plus.

Other zero-width characters are available ([space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), [non-joiner](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm), [joiner](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm)), and you might see something different in your dump - it just has to be something your client doesn't display at all. Whatever is in there, if it affects all rows and not just that single ticket, then how and why is probably down to whatever front-end/application populates the table - possibly from a character set mismatch, but it could be intentional. If it is just that ticket then that note is an interesting test...

Comment: Indeed, dump was the key to all of this. I still do not understand what the difference between DUMP(x) and DUMP(x,1000) is, but the result with the latter turns out to be ```Typ=1 Len=32: <,h,t,m,l,>,t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,a, ,t,e,s,t, ,n,o,t,e,<,/,h,t,m,l,>``` which is related to the application. Thanks again

Comment: OK... the `<html>` part is visible in SQL\*Plus etc. (and in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba837adb06650691a434080971964393)); so curious which client you used that did not display it? (SQL Developer hides it in query output, but shows it in script output; what you posted doesn't look like it came from the results grid.) More confusingly, that should report the first space in position 11, not 7.

Comment: I'm using a custom client developed inside my company that works as a data portal. I'm assuming the surrounding of html notes was designed like this so that every CRM and data portal we use is able to render the note correctly as long as it supports html.  Plus, I don't know why I typed 7, the result is 11 as you say.